# how to read char from bits in c?

Tags: c, bitmap, char, bit

I would like to modify a char by shifting it (and thus changing its value) and the return the result instead of that previous char:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char * str = calloc(4, sizeof(char));
    printf("what bit to set [0-31]\n");
    int a;  
    scanf(" %i", &a);
    int byte = a/8;
    int offset = a%8;
    
    str[byte] = (str[byte] >> offset) & (char)255; //how to return the modified char? 
    
    for(int i =0; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j =0; j<8 ; j++)
            printf("%i", (str[i] >> (7-j)) & 1); //print the results
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

*output*:

```
what bit to set [0-31]
20
00000000
00000000
00000000 // I want 00001000
00000000
```

Comment: When posting code like this, it's much better if you remove code handling user input and hard code the value for `a` instead.

Comment: Obviously `(str[byte] >> offset) & (char)255` this is 0&1 which returns 0.... Probably something like `(1 >> offset) & 255`?

Comment: The solution is this: `str[byte] ^= 1UL << (7-offset);`